# XSL : Unable to retrieve(copy) element content?

Tags: xml, xslt

I do not understand why my element content is not getting copied ?

i.e. My xml current output looks like this

```
<root>
  <foo>some content</foo>
  <set>
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key</set-key>
      <set-val/>
    </set-element>     
  </set>
</root>
```

So the idea is that i want to copy whats in the  element into  element. Expected output should be

```
<root>
  <foo>some content</foo>
  <set>
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key</set-key>
      <set-val>some content</set-val>
    </set-element> 
  </set>
</root>
```

My xsl template looks like this

```
<axsl:template match="set">
    <axsl:copy>
        <axsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        <set-element>
            <set-key>some-key</set-key>
            <set-val><axsl:value-of select="foo"/></set-val>
        </set-element>
    </axsl:copy>
</axsl:template>
```

I have tried many things inc:

```
<value><axsl:value-of select="root/foo"/></value>
<value><axsl:value-of select="root/foo/text()"/></value>
<value><axsl:value-of select="foo/text()"/></value>
<value><axsl:value-of select="foo/*"/></value>
```

As well as i have tried to save whats int the foo element as parameter and then use that parameter in value:of but still no success
Can any one see the problem with my template ?

**EDIT:**

What if i have multiple set-elements in my set, i.e.

```
<root>
  <foo>some content</foo>
  <set>
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key</set-key>
      <set-val>some content</set-val>
    </set-element> 
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key-2</set-key>
      <set-val>some content-2</set-val>
    </set-element> 
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key-3</set-key>
      <set-val/>
    </set-element> 
  </set>
</root>
```

And i want to add `<foo>` content to that 3rd element ??
As of my understanding this will require the `<xsl:template match=value>` to have some parameter that will specify which value to modify ?

Comment: How do you decide when to set `set-val` to the content of `foo`, i.e. what is the exact condition? My solution works fine if you want to do this for _all_ `set-val` elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your approach is *context*. XPath expressions can be relative and their resolution depends on where exactly you are in the XML tree.

In other words, if your template matches `set`, then the following line:

```
<axsl:value-of select="foo"/>
```

retrieves a *child node* of `set` whose element name is "foo". (But, of course, this child node does not exist).

To find nodes regardless of the context, use `//` in an expression. But I'd recommend you do not use it as long as you can refer to nodes from within the context, e.g. via axes like `preceding-sibling`.

**Stylesheet (edited)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="set-val[preceding-sibling::set-key='some-key-3']">
  <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:value-of select="parent::set-element/parent::set/preceding-sibling::foo[1]"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output (edited)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
  <foo>foo content</foo>
  <set>
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key</set-key>
      <set-val>some content</set-val>
    </set-element> 
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key-2</set-key>
      <set-val>some content-2</set-val>
    </set-element> 
    <set-element>
      <set-key>some-key-3</set-key>
      <set-val>foo content</set-val>
    </set-element> 
  </set>
</root>
```

Note that I have changed your input. The text content of `foo` is now "foo content".

Comment: Thank you Mathias, your solution works fine :) i just edited my question as i am curious what if i have multiple set-val elements how do i determine which to modify ?

Comment: See my comment above. Do you want to modify all of them or just some of them?

Comment: just one of them .i.e. the 3rd one only in the above example

Comment: Please try to be exact and tell me the _condition_. Is it the third one because of its position (always the third one) or because of the text content of `set-key`?

Comment: ah ok, so its because of the set-key, if that set key will be 3rd then i want to modify 3rd set-element, if 5th then 5th set-element and so on